# How to set Checkbox by default checked in treeview

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I am trying to set treeview with checkbox and there are some check box are by default checked , here my data source value:-

```
[{"id":12,"Name":"Shirts","hasChildren":false,"Checked":true}
,{"id":13,"Name":"Jeans","hasChildren":false,"Checked":false},
{"id":14,"Name":"Shoes","hasChildren":false,"Checked":true},
{"id":15,"Name":"Apparel accessories","hasChildren":false,"Checked":false}]
```

and my view page code:--

```
                       $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#category-treeview").kendoTreeView({
                            dataSource: categories,
                            dataTextField: "Name",
                            checkboxes: true
                    });
                });
```

but i no one checkbox is selected why?

Can any advice how to solve this?

Regards,
vinit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is basically correct. The only problem is that `Checked` needs to be `checked` (lowercase). Your data would look like:

```
var categories = [
    {"id":12,"Name":"Shirts","hasChildren":false,"checked":true},
    {"id":13,"Name":"Jeans","hasChildren":false,"checked":false},
    {"id":14,"Name":"Shoes","hasChildren":false,"checked":true},
    {"id":15,"Name":"Apparel accessories","hasChildren":false,"checked":false}
];
```

I put your code with this small change here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/78k2b/

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is show whether the checkbox is checked or not, you can easily employ a templateFunction for the checkbox.

```
checkboxes: {
    template: checkboxTemplate
}
```

And use a function something like

```
function checkboxTemplate(e) {
  if(e.item.Checked) {
    return "<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' />";
  } 
  else {
    return "<input type='checkbox' />";
  }
}
```

The issue with this approach, is there isn't a two-way data-binding happening.  So if you change a checkbox, and them dump the dataSource, that change isn't reflected.

If you are needing two-way data-binding, so you can post the changes back, you will need to employ something quite a bit more complicated.  It is laid out pretty well in this SO post ([Binding checkboxes in treeview with checkboxes that uses remote datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443683/binding-checkboxes-in-treeview-with-checkboxes-that-uses-remote-datasource)).

I have looked for a more elegant answer to this, as it would seem fairly common, but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: I think that you could even resolve the two-way data-binding issue by specifying the data-role or name attributes, but this would require some hours of "reverse engineering" of the widget behaviour